# Dynamic Array. Size ignored. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, size

I am new to C++. I try to understand Memory Management in C++ and also to work with pointers.
I have a question about dynamic array.

```
//This is the part of my code:
int *ptr;
ptr = new int[3];
ptr[0] = 1;
ptr[1] = 2;
ptr[2] = 3;
// Normally I would think I cannot add further elements to the array, but it is possible
ptr[3] = 4;
ptr[4] = 5; 
ptr[5] = ...
```

So, my question is why am I able to add further elements to the array when I initialized the size of Array with size = 3 ?

On the one hand, it makes sense that my array can grow "dynamically". On the other hand it makes no sense because of this line:

```
ptr = new int[3];
```

Comment: You're invoking an undefined behavior.

Comment: To answer you "why" part, C/C++ dont bounds check arrays. They believe in allowing you to shoot yourself in hard to trace ways. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding new elements into array, you are just overwriting some random patch of memory adjacent to your array.

Accessing an array element is merely accessing a shifted pointer to the first element:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = new int[3]; // This code allocates 12 bytes, say 0x12340000 - 0x1234000B. ptr = 0x12340000 (note 4 bytes for each integer)
ptr[2] = 5; // This code sets integer at 0x12340000+2*sizeof(int) = 0x12340008
ptr[3] = 6; // This code sets an "integer" at 0x12340000+3*sizeof(int) = 0x1234000C - which is outside your array
ptr[10000000] = 7; // This or something like this will crash your program
```

You are just lucky this does not lead to a crash - in other circumstances, it would.

General advice: you can't add elements to an array, if you need to change size of a collection later - use [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: s/lucky/unlucky/ - in cases like this, a crash is a *good* thing; it lets you know there's a problem.  What would be bad is if it didn't crash, but left your program in a bad state.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of array.

Answer (score 1):

Exceeding an array bounds is undefined behaviour. That's why.

In this case you are lucky to get the output. But undefined Behavior means that the program can explode your computer next time ;)

So, don't do that.